How does phenomenology account for the dissociation between experience and knowledge?
I would like to ask whether it is possible to account, in phenomenological terms (Husserlian if possible), for a dissociation between experience and knowledge.
Let us imagine that someone sees an oasis in the desert. His companions, experts in optics and psychology, explain to him that it is not what it seems, that there is no oasis there. He understands what is happening, he grasps the noema, but his experience, his noesis (and even the perceptual contents or hyletic data), remains that of seeing an oasis.
Is it possible to account for this dissociation between perception and knowledge, and more generally for a dissociation between experience and object, in phenomenological terms?
Furthermore: what happens when the experience changes, and the oasis is no longer experienced as such, but as the desert it actually is?
Thank you for your help.

Do you mean intentional inexistence? "Following the lead of Edmund Husserl... the point of the phenomenological analysis has been to show that the essential property of intentionality of being directed onto something is not contingent upon whether some real physical target exists independently of the intentional act itself." The knowledge only comes with  fulfillment of intention by available evidence.

@Conifold Not exactly. An object can be perceived or thought of in different ways. If I’m visiting a wax museum and I spot what appears to be a woman waving at me, but, getting closer, I realize that she's actually a wax figure, the way the object is presented in my first visual experience is different from how it is presented in my second experience. The meaning, or sense, of the first perception is entirely distinct from that of the second. Husserl describes this shift as an “explosion” of the initial perception, which is replaced by a different one. (Cf. LI, Investigation I, §12).

@Conifold magine thinking of Napoleon as "the victor at Jena" in one instance and then later as "the defeated at Waterloo." Although both thoughts refer to the same individual, Napoleon, he is presented through two different noematic senses in these experiences. Each sense points to the same person, but it portrays Napoleon in distinct ways. This are the kind of descriptions I'm looking for.


"That, as appearance, the being [mirage] can deceive us is the condition of the possibility of our deceiving ourselves rather than the other way round."
from The Origin of the Work of Art (1935-36), page 30.

Each being
which we encounter and which encounters us maintains this strange
opposition of presence in that at the same time it always holds
itself back in a concealment. Concealment, however, reigns in the
midst of beings, in a twofold  manner.
Beings refuse themselves to us down to that one and seemingly most
trivial feature which we meet most immediately when all we can say of
a being is that it is. Concealment as refusal is not primarily or only
the  limit of knowledge in each particular case; it is, rather, the
beginning of  the clearing of what is illuminated. But concealment,
though of course of  another sort, also occurs within the illuminated.
Beings push themselves in  front of others, the one hides the other,
this casts that into shadow, a few  obstruct many, on occasion one
denies all. Concealment, here, is not simple  refusal. Rather, a being
indeed appears but presents itself as other than it is.
This concealment is an obstructing [Verstellen]. If beings did not
obstruct  one another we could not err in seeing and doing, we could
not go astray  and transgress, and, in particular, could not overreach
ourselves. That, as appearance, the being can deceive us is the
condition of the possibility of our deceiving ourselves rather than
the other way round.
Concealment can be either a refusal or merely an obstructing. We are
never really certain whether it is the one or the other. Concealment
conceals  and obstructs itself. This means: the open place in the
midst of beings, the  clearing, is never a fixed stage with a
permanently raised curtain on which  the play of beings enacts itself.
Rather, the clearing happens only as this twofold concealment.

